# Fingerprint Scanner on smartphones and standalone fingerprint scanner

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to ask if we can validate the fingerprint output from standalone fingerprint scanner with the build in fingerprint scanner on smartphones..

How difficult it will be to integrate both technologies?
Take note that I will only use Android Smartphones..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Android Fingerprint API could only match fingerprint register from the device.
In the `authenticate` method you can't pass fingeprint image or template: see [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#authenticate%28android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20int,%20android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback,%20android.os.Handler%29)

It's the same on all consumer devices (Apple, Samsung, HTC, ...) you can't get template or image of fingerpint.

Comment: I searched that every device/smartphone brand has its own fingerprint API.. if the integration between standalone scanner and thus from smartphones.. is it possible that the output from different smartphone scanner is same?

Comment: With Fingerprint  API from Android and Pass API (fingerprint) from Samsung it's not possible ot get image or template of scanned fingerprint

Comment: @R.S.Abarro, is it useful ?

Comment: so there's no other way of consuming the Fingerprint API from android and Pass API of Samsung? no other way of integrating it with an android app?

Comment: No there's external USB fingerprint scanner with specific API working on Android, it's the only way. Please accept answer if it's useful ?